# Format JS datetime to correct ISO format

Tags: angular, postgresql, typescript, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been trying for a few days now to get my server side code (C#) to save a timestamp sent via an API call to Postgres.

It seems to work fine if I attach `DateTime.Now()` to the data transfer object but when I try and parse a datetime sent from the client i get a 400 with

```
**0: "The input was not valid."**.
```

As my response.

My classes look like this

TS:

```
export interface ArtistShows {
    showDate: string;
    venue: string;
    id?: string;
    bandsAlsoPlaying: Array<string>;
}
```

C#

```
public class ArtistShow
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShowDate { get; set; }
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string BandsAlsoPlaying { get; set; }

    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

Method that maps new form (w/ouputted Date) (TS)

```
private _mapNewShowForm(): ArtistShows {
    let showDate = this.newShowForm.get(this.newShowFormEnum.DATE).value;
    let convertedShowDate = new Date(showDate);

    return {
      bandsAlsoPlaying: [],
      showDate: convertedShowDate.toISOString(),
      venue: `${this.newShowForm.get(this.newShowFormEnum.VENUE).value}, ${this.newShowForm.get(this.newShowFormEnum.CITY).value}`
    };
}
```

Date format from request: "2019-01-04T00:00:00.000Z"
Required format: "2018-12-29 20:23:22.667766" <-- Dates are stored in PG as timestamp without timezone

My question is, does anyone know what format I should be sending my date to backend in (I heard it's ISO 8601)? Should I even be doing anything to the Date on the client? And how can I convert my JS date to a date that will save in PG?

I am also using Microsoft Entity Framework Core with Postgres (if that helps)

Comment: Try to use `moment.js` lib. It's perfect for working with datetime.


https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ - docs for formatting with `moment.js`. 

By default `moment().format()` returns current datetime in ISO 8601.

Comment: I will have a look at it (I've had the docs saved in my bookmarks for ages), but I'd really like to understand how to convert a date to ISO 8061 without help from a library.

Comment: According to this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString . `toISOString` method returns ISO8601 format of date.

Comment: Also you could try to convert it to timestamp via  `getTime` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime.

Comment: I'd recommend `date-fns` over `moment.js`, as the latter is a resource hog dependency-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I honestly forgot I'd opened this question. I asked again 6 months later and got the answer I was looking for:

[Parse JS Date.toIsoString in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505742/parse-js-date-toisostring-in-c-sharp)

In the end the answer was just using `Convert.ToDateTime()` and it gave me the exact date format I needed.

Closing this question!

Answer (score 1):

use unix_timestamp As a basic format and convert them according to you need

get unix timestamp in c# :

```
var timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

get Datetime from unix timestamp in c# :

```
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1549741828).DateTime;
```

get unix timestamp in javascript :

```
let timestamp = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
```

get Datetime from unix timestamp in c# :

```
let date = new Date(1549742450 * 1000)
```